# How do I pronounce our moderator's name?

Tags: discussion

I was looking at the profiles of ELU moderators and came across the profile of [Matt E.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3559/matt-e-%d0%ad%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd)(can't read the last name)

[image]

Now, how do I read their last name? What character set is used? How's it pronounced? Sorry if I sound silly but let's say my curiosity got the better of me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pronounce my surname /ɛlən/. As in Ellen DeGeneres or 'elen of Troy.

It's the regular font, displaying Cyrillic characters.

Comment: Great to hear it straight from the horse's mouth! Well, in this case, a weird greenish yawning alien's! :) :P

Comment: The exact font, I believe, is Black Crag Cyrillic.

Comment: You should have answered: ["My name is Ellen. Matt Ellen."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXxKZkE2MGo)

Comment: Honestly? Given the profile image, I was expecting something a response a bit more like "Are you sum koinna *git!?* Me **name**... iz Matt. E. WAAAGH!"